# Как использовать события?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вот хоть убей - не могу понять как мне использовать события вот этого плагина https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid

например мне нужно выдать алерт по событию `vast.adStart` как это сделать?=)

Comment: там же пример есть: [`player.on('reset', function () {`](https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid#playervast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну вот так и использовать, [тут](https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid#plugin-events) все события описаны.

```
player.on('vast.adStart', function () {
    alert(true);
});
```